# are virtual destructors in novtable interfaces okay?

Tags: c++

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 project where I have an interface class that is declared `_declspec( novtable )`. For example:

```
class _declspec( novtable ) IFoo
{
public:
    virtual void FooDo() const = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo
{
public:
    ~Foo() { printf( "~Foo()\r\n" ); };
    void FooDo() const { printf( "FooDo()\r\n" ); };
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    IFoo* foo = new Foo();
    foo->FooDo();
    delete foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Because `IFoo` does not have a virtual destructor, the concrete `Foo` destructor is never called.

Output:

```
FooDo()
```

Desired Output:

```
FooDo()
~Foo()
```

But, in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), there is a dire warning against calling functions in interface classes declared `novtable`. "*If you attempt to instantiate a class marked with novtable and then access a class member, you will receive an access violation (AV)*." So adding a `virtual ~IFoo() { };` member sounds like it could be a Bad Thing. (although in my testing, it seems to work fine.)

How does one properly get the desired behavior from this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be fine to include a virtual destructor in your interface class. You've already included another virtual method and called it, so the destructor should be no different.

The effect of `novtable` is that the *vtable of `IFoo`* doesn't get initialized. That's OK, though, since you never directly instantiate `IFoo`. Instead, you instantiate a descendant of that class. The descendant has a vtable, and *that* vtable gets initialized properly with pointers to methods of `Foo` (and `IFoo`, if `IFoo` has any non-pure virtual methods that `Foo` doesn't override). The call to `~IFoo` from within `Foo` is a non-virtual dispatch, so the vtable of `IFoo` still isn't required.

Comment: Though I called a virtual function `FooDo`, it was pure virtual and had no implementation whereas a destructor cannot be pure virtual and must have an implementation (though empty). My fear was that difference would meet the criteria of "*invoking a class member*".